# Any way to deal with multiple entries for one field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, excel

I'm mapping out parcel numbers from an excel spreadsheet, matching them to the county APN field in a shapefile , which is in the format ###-###-##. My spreadsheet has four fields that I've concatenated to create the whole APN. I've run into a problem:

My final field sometimes contains multiple numbers (when a particular map covers more than one parcel). Is there a way to select all of the numbers in this field and have them selected out i.e.  the concat field would appear as such "100-184-12,13,17" and I want all three parcels picked "100-184-12",""100-184-13", and "100-184-17".

Comment: I would suggest having only a single question in your post. [Framing (asking) good Questions for GIS Stack Exchange?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/framing-asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange/3353)

Comment: I think you should try to explain better your problem: do you want to apply this "rule" while importing the spreadsheet? Or maybe do you want to edit the properties of your imported after the import? And so on...

Comment: I would like to join the spreadsheet to the parcel shapefile and then delete all the remaining parcels that do not have a match. I would then save the shapefile as a new one. I want the selection to occur during the join.

Comment: Your comment is referring to one objective and your question in the post appears to be asking something else? Also, good job on editing out the '000' padding question, if you want you could ask about the question in it's own post. I would recommend searching about it prior to posting if needed.